# Web SQL UPDATE query not working

Tags: javascript, sql, cordova, phonegap-plugins, web-sql

I am trying to update a table in an Phonegap Cordova App using Web SQL.
Following is the function that i have built for updating record but it is not updating the database nor giving any error.

```
function updatedrink(x, y, z) {
    alert(x);
    alert(y);
    alert(z);

    db = window.openDatabase("smartbar", "1.0", "Smart Bar", 10000);
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql("UPDATE drinks SET name=?, qty=? WHERE pos=?", [y, z, x], function(tx, result) {
            alert('Updated');
        }, function(error) {
            alert(error);
        });
    });
}
```

All the alert statements are giving the correct values but table is not updated. No matter how much i try i cannot point out a single mistake. Please rescue.

Comment: Using `console.log` is a much better way to debug. If you're sure the query is correct, make sure you have the right update permissions in your db

Comment: @SterlingArcher can you please guide me how to check Update Permission in DB